# Authenticating Users From a Website/App in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, riot-games-api

I am working on an app that players of League of Legends can create profiles of themselves; but I need to authenticate them to prevent creating fake accounts of other players. League has it's own messaging app for mobile, so can I authenticate users with that app? Or should I use an API/library for this task? How can I achieve that in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though League of Legends has authentication for their apps, but its not available to third parties as yet, but they are working on it. One of the devs commented on the matter in the [developer portal](https://discussion.developer.riotgames.com/questions/6153/oauth-for-league-of-legends-account.html).

Alternatively, you could use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) to allow your users to sign in with their email or other methods.

Comment: Hello. Yes they are working on it but I need to know how to achieve that on my own as mentioned in question. I am using Firebase Auth but you know, they can create profile with their own e-mail and they still can fake other people's Summoner Name's.